# Laravel socalite - handleProviderCallback is never triggered

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am trying to log a user in via Facebook and then use that user data to fill out the name and email in a comment form.

I am using `Laravel / Socialite`.

So in my `LoginController` I have this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

        return redirect()->route('blog');


        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

By using breakpoints in both methods I came to the conclusion that the `handleProviderCallback` method is actually never triggered for some reason.

So to make it clear, `redirectToProvider` is triggered and it works, it does log me in via Facebook, but the `handleProviderCallback` method is never triggered so I can't get user data.

Answer (score 0):

first please check your function definition it is wrong

```
public function public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
```

and to store data in session you can also use

```
Session::put(['key' => 'value']);
```

Comment: I just pasted the whole controller, however I've edited my Q, the issue is not with sessions but the method `handleProviderCallback` is never triggered.